# IMsTscAx Remote Desktop Certificate Info in C++

Tags: c++, certificate, rdp

I'm trying to get certificate information from my C++ Rdp program when it fires OnAuthenticationWarningDisplayed(). Usually when i connect through mstsc.exe the remote desktop shows a certificate but when i connect through c++ it doesn't show it. My code looks like this:

```
lpUnk->QueryInterface(IID_IMsRdpClientNonScriptable5, (void**)&pns);
m_pMsTsc->get_SecuredSettings2(&pss);
m_pMsTsc->get_AdvancedSettings2(&padv);
m_pMsTsc->put_Server(L"192.168.248.131");
padv->put_RDPPort(3389);
m_pMsTsc->put_Domain(L"Workgroup");
m_pMsTsc->put_UserName(L"home");
pns->put_ClearTextPassword(L"qwe123oke");
pns->put_EnableCredSspSupport(TRUE);
```

So i get the warning on:

```
void CMainFrame::OnAuthenticationWarningDisplayed()
{
AfxMessageBox(L"OnAuthenticationWarningDisplayed");
}
```

My question is: how can i display or get certificate information that appear when i connect through mstsc.exe ? Unfortunately msdn has no documentation on this subject. Any idea is very much appreciated!